# Acceder a las variables/datos de ajustes en android referentes a la utilidad como hotspot (compartir internet)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Estaba intentando imprimir por un Textview los datos de compartir internet de mi sistema android pero no estoy encontrando información alguna de como acceder a ellos.

mi idea es pasarle al tex un string con el nombre asignado a la red de compartir internet, pero no estoy encontrando nada referente a acceder a este tipo de variables/datos de los ajustes

```
    tex = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tex.setText("hello world");
```

He conseguido encontrar como puede accederse al wifi

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

Pero no consigo desde ahí acceder a los datos de compartir internet para poner nombre de la red y eso, he probado el debug pero no me sale nada que parezca eso, alguien sabe si es que no es ese context y cual es ?